# Se puede tener la parte front con solo html,css,JS en una solución distinta a la del back (web api) [ASP]

Tags: asp, webapi

La situación es la siguiente me dieron una carpeta con el back y front de un pagina web pero estas a su vez la dividen en dos carpetas diferentes (dos soluciones visual studio distintas):

proyecto->back

proyecto->front

lo que no se es como el front que es una solución distinta esta accediendo al controlador del back dado que el back es una web api y esta en otra solución.

Cabe resaltar que el front solo tiene archivos html, css y javascript y la supuesta conexión la hace con ajax mandado los datos por json a la web api.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask]. En cuanto a tu pregunta, no queda clara cuál es la duda. ¿Tienes algún problema específico de programación con alguna parte del `proyecto`? Te invito a [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/254010/edit) tu pregunta y agregarle lo necesario. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Puedes tener un proyecto con 2 o n proyecto dentro de el.
- El front-end claro que puede acceder al back-end para que esto sea posible se tiene 
  que referenciar en el front-end el proyecto al que quiere acceder su métodos, clases 
  como es el caso de un proyecto api.

  Aquí te dejo la pantalla donde se referencia un proyecto a otro.Hay que tener en cuenta 
  también de la arquitectura del proyecto en este caso el font-end no accede directamente 
  al proyecto Api. En este proyecto como el Api también puede referenciar a otros 
  proyectos.
  Saludos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar, entiendo que para consumir la web api el Front debe referenciar a esta, sin embargo en el proyecto que se me asigno se publico la web api  como sistema de archivos en la carpeta bin  de la carpeta Front, ahora el problema es que no me consume el servicio, cuando se hace una petición al servicio este se redirecciona al localhost con el que se depuraba antes de ser publicado...sigo en el siguiente comentario

Comment: por ejemplo el web api se depuraba en localhost:57736 y el front en localhost:64593 al momento de publicar la web api en la carpeta del front se supone debe ahora ejecutarse en el localhost del front, sin embargo la web api se redirecciona al localhost:57736  en vez de dirijirse a localhost:64593.

Comment: Cada proyecto es independiente y se publica en una  URL diferente.Lo único que hace el front-end es consumir el proyecto web api.

Comment: Muchas gracias por aclarar mi duda.